# Matlab Create Arrays from folders and filenames depending on filepath

Tags: arrays, matlab, directory

Ok so let's say I have the following folder structure

```
\folder
        \A
           \q1
              \aaaa.jpg
              \bbbb.jpg
              \cccc.jpg
              \desktop.ini  (*hidden file*) 
           \q2
              \eeee.jpg
              \ffff.jpg
              \gggg.jpg
        \B 
           \q1
              \hhhh.jpg
              \iiii.jpg
              \desktop.ini  (*hidden file*)
```

I want to create 4 arrays.

```
Names = [A , B]
A_q1 = [aaaa , bbbb , cccc]
A_q2 = [eeee , ffff , gggg]
B_q1 = [hhhh , iiii]
```

I tried using dir as shown below

```
allFiles = dir( 'c:\my\folder' );
allNames = { allFiles.name };
```

to create *Names* array and I got ".", ".." along with the other files.

> [How can I exclude them? Also how can I only get folder names in *Names* and **NOT** any file names.]

No need for that, I managed to work around it later on the program.

So how can I create the other Arrays? The Folder Depth is always the same, and .jpg files are stored in q1,q2,q3 etc folders.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [What are ./ and ../ directories?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63081/what-are-and-directories).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link. But I could not understand exactly how to do it. Anyway I found a way to work around this. I intend to use the "Names" Array to create Excel Sheets for each name. So since "." and ".." are always the first two I can start from the third cell.

Answer (score 0):

First make some variables containing main path and subpath for ease of use then use `ls` command to read files of desired extension. Use '[ ]' to conacatenate paths.
Ex-

```
main_path = 'D:\folder';
sub_path11 = '\A';
sub_path12 = '\B';
sub_path21 = '\q1';
sub_path21 = '\q2';
ext = '*.jpg';

img_names1 = ls([main_path sub_path11 sub_path21 ext]);
img_names2 = ls([main_path sub_path11 sub_path22 ext]);
img_names3 = ls([main_path sub_path12 sub_path21 ext]);
```

You can read the image files having variable length name using-

```
path1 = [main_path sub_path11 sub_path21];
for i = 1:size(img_names1,1)
   file_name = fscanf(img_names1(i,:),'%s');   % for removing the extra spaces at the end of filename
   img = imread([path1 '/' file_name]);
   ...
   ...
end
```

You can also use relative path instead (i.e with respect to your current location of files) using '../' and '/' operators.

and regarding '.' and '..', you can use following code to eliminate it

```
img_data = dir([main_path sub_path11 sub_path21]);
FileNames = {img_data.name};
FileNames(ismember(FileNames,{'.','..'})) = [];
```